# Powershell returns a different Filesize from Actual

Tags: powershell-3.0

Powershell is returning a different filesize`(46)` on querying an mp4 file with file.Length command .

Actual file size is `32029227` .

Also tried using `Get-Item` and `Get-ItemPropertyValue` but the file is not found by Powershell , eventhough it clearly exists.

Why is there this discrepancy?

```
***Console***  

    PS C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode> dir

    Directory: C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       19-08-2020     15:59       32029227 Produce.mp4


PS C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode> $pd_output = 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4'.Length

PS C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode> $pd_output

46  



 PS C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode> $pd_output = (Get-Item 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4').Length

Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:15
+ ... d_output = (Get-Item 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4' ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\User0\...ert\Produce.mp4:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
     


PS C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_transcode> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4' -Name Length 

Get-ItemPropertyValue : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ItemPropertyValue 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\User0\...ert\Produce.mp4:String) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell was returning the string values and not the actual filesize in the command below -

```
 $pd_output = 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4'.Length
```

In the Get-Item and Get-ItemPropertyValue the -Path flag was missing .On providing this flag the correct filesize is returned.

```
 $pd_output = (Get-Item -Path 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4').Length  

 $pd_output = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'C:\Users\User0\Desktop\kcg_convert\Produce.mp4'  -Name Length
```